# MySQL - select rows with limit

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

How can I select a certain number of rows, based on a condition (using `IN` or any other conditional), and if the number of rows returned by the condition is less than `LIMIT x` then to select from the remainig rows until the `LIMIT x` is met?

So, if I have the following table:

```
id   comment   ord
1    ...       null
2    ...       1
3    ...       2
4    ...       null
```

then the result set should be, using `LIMIT 3`:

```
id   comment   ord
2    ...       1
3    ...       2
1    ...       null
```

If the `ord` column is not null, then I want to select the respective row(s), if not, I want to select one or more from the rest of the rows, having `ord` NULL, until the `LIMIT 3` condition is reached.

Another example, if I have the next table data:

```
id   comment   ord
1    ...       3
2    ...       1
3    ...       2
4    ...       null
```

Then the result set should be

```
id   comment   ord
2    ...       1
3    ...       2
1    ...       3
```

I have tried this mysql code:

```
SELECT t.* FROM table t 
WHERE 
    t.ord IN (SELECT t1.ord FROM table t1 WHERE t1.ord IS NOT NULL ORDER BY t1.ord ASC) 
    OR 
    t.id IN (SELECT t2.id FROM table t2 WHERE t2.ord IS NULL ORDER BY t2.id ASC)
LIMIT 3;
```

But I always get the rows that have `ord NULL`, even if I have some `ord` columns not null.

Any help please?

Comment: Add an order by clause?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Hmm, I don't understand you quite well...

Comment: You’re asking for three random rows from the database. If you want the ones with ord not null first, then add an ODER BY that says you want them first

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I did that, but the result-set is the same, ignoring the ones having `ord` not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the check for whether `ord` is null in your `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY ord IS NULL, ord, id
LIMIT 3
```

`ord IS NULL` will be `0` for non-null `ord`, `1` for null `ord`, so this will put all the non-null rows first. Within those it will order by `ord`, then the remainder will be ordered by `id`.

Then `LIMIT 3` will select the first 3 of all of these.